# How can I use datepicker for filter in p:dateTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am new in jsf with primeFaces.I am trying to filter DateTable with datepicker.I made DateTable filter when i select the date from datepicket filter works, but When I delete text from the field, the filter is still active.How can i fix that this is my code from xhtml.

```
<p:column headerText="Date" filterBy="#{example.date}" sortBy="#{example.date}" filterMatchMode="contains">                   

                   <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:calendar  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                          <p:ajax event="dateSelect"  oncomplete="PF('table').filter()"/>
                         </p:calendar>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="#{example.date}">
                    </h:outputText>
```

How can i handle event on filter text input change?

Comment: Check for a different  event in addition to dateSelect....

Comment: Thanks for reply , i slove problem adding event "onblur". This is my code now <f:facet name="filter"> <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" onblur="PF('table').filter()"> <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('table').filter()" /> </p:calendar> </f:facet>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slove problem adding event "onblur". This is my code now

```
 <f:facet name="filter"> 
<p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" onblur="PF('table').filter()"> 
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('table').filter()" />
</p:calendar> 
</f:facet>
```